# Awk previous day

Tags: awk

For some reason I can not get this work?  I want to compare a previous day and a current days file.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$2;next}{print $1,$2-a[FNR]}' Router_Evi_`(strftime("%y-%m-%d", systime()-86400))`.txt Router_Evi_`(date +"%y-%m-%d")`.txt > temp_plus_minus.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: All is see is a quoting/backticks nightmare.. not a question. What is the contents of the files and what are you trying to achieve i.e the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

you are confused with awk script and shell's `$(..)` or

```
`...`
```

the command you gave is:

```
awk '....' foo_`(awkcode)`.txt bar_`(shell cmd)`.txt
                    ^
---problem----------|
```

this won't work. since you cannot let shell interpret and execute your awk code. You should write shell command/code in the backticks. or like this:

```
foo_$(awk 'BEGIN{print strftime("%y-%m-%d", systime()-86400)}').txt
```

It would be better getting the two filenames in variables first(if they are dynamic), and then call awk script. making everything into one line not always the best solution.